What are the ways of Accessing attributes of images `<img>` inside ng-image-slider (specifically `onerror` to show default src if img src not found)
I am using an <ng-image-slider> inside angular component to display sliding images. If the source of the image is not available then I want my slider to show default image (with taken into consideration that default image is definitely present). How to do it ?
I have seen to handle such issues we use onerror event for <img> tag. so it would be (error) event handler in angular but how can I do that for an image inside ng-image-slider ?
Here's the plugin for <ng-image-slider>:
[1]: https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider

Do it via plain JS before passsing to ng-image-slider: Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have to create an extra function that will perform the set of default image, if no image is present.
images = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.setDefaultImageIfNotPresent();
}

setDefaultImageIfNotPresent() {
    if (this.imageObject?.length) {
        this.images = this.imageObject.map((item: any) => {
        item.image = item.image || 'https://placehold.co/600x400';
        item.thumbImage = item.thumbImage || 'https://placehold.co/600x400';
        return item;
    });
    }
}

Stackblitz Demo
